# Spring Boot 1.4.2 @WebMvcTest returns status 404

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, spring-boot, jersey

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.2 and Jersey (jax-rs) to create a REST controller. I have followed the documentation on how to test REST Controllers ([Testing the Spring MVC slice](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4)). But my test returns 404 and I can't seem to find out why. The controller here is simplified but the problem remains.

My question is how to get the 200 status when running the test?

**HealthController.java**

```
@Controller
@Path("/health")
public class HealthController {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Health health() {
        return Health.up().build();
    }
}
```

**Running the server and doing a query gives me this**

```
%> curl -i http://localhost:8080/health
HTTP/1.1 200 
X-Application-Context: application
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 21
Date: Sun, 27 Nov 2016 15:22:30 GMT

{
  "status" : "UP"
}%
```

**HealthControllerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HealthController.class)
public class HealthControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void health() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/health").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()); // 200 expected
    }
}
```

**This is what I get when running test**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2016-11-27 16:22:08.254  INFO 9029 --- [           main] no.avec.controller.HealthControllerTest  : Starting HealthControllerTest on ducati.local with PID 9029 (started by avec in /Users/avec/Projects/RESTdemo)
2016-11-27 16:22:08.257 DEBUG 9029 --- [           main] no.avec.controller.HealthControllerTest  : Running with Spring Boot v1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.4.RELEASE
2016-11-27 16:22:08.257  INFO 9029 --- [           main] no.avec.controller.HealthControllerTest  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-11-27 16:22:09.294  INFO 9029 --- [           main] no.avec.controller.HealthControllerTest  : Started HealthControllerTest in 1.421 seconds (JVM running for 2.132)

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /health
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Accept=[application/json]}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

Comment: Are you also using Web security Config?

Comment: Probably your controller is not picked up by Spring when the context for your test is created. Try using  '@SpringBootTest' combined with '@AutoConfigureMockMvc' as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html.

Comment: When you *curl* ing the `/health` endpoint, which one is getting called: Spring Boot actuator's health endpoint or your custom controller? IMHO, actuator's endpoint is the reason that the `curl -i http://localhost:8080/health` is successful and your controller is not getting picked up at all

Comment: @zubair-nabi No I am not.

Comment: @AliDehghani org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health

Comment: @Tom Your solution worked for testing the HealthController. Status 200 returned. But it did not work for my actual Controller. Still 404 there. My other controller returns Iterable<Person> via GET.

Comment: What do you mean with "it did not work for my actual controller"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the `@Path` and `@GET` annotations you are using JAX-RS rather than Spring MVC. `@WebMvcTest` is specifically for testing the web slice implemented using Spring MVC. It filters out components that aren't Spring MVC controllers so it won't work with a web API implemented using JAX-RS.

Comment: Yes I am using JAX-RS. I created a Spring Controller and then it worked. Still I did get the JAX-RS Controller to be tested with the tip from @Tom in the comment above (initial question)

Comment: I was playing with this idea a while back (while I was trying to use it for restdocs), and it _is_ possible. You need to register an instance of the [ServletContainer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.java#L149) (which is a filter and a servlet) with the MockMvcBuilders. I was trying earlier to reproduce the same results, but I couldn't do it. Not sure exactly what I did last time. All that I remember is that it was really hacky :-)

Comment: @peeskillet Interesting and might be what I am after. To bad you do not remember. Though hacky is seldom good.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your Controller class, it's a bit confusing. You're using `@Controller` and then `@Path`and `@GET` annotations which means you're using Jersey. I'll recommend to use `@Component`instead. Although, `@Controller` extends `@Component` but still....

Anyway, you should use `org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate` for testing your rest resources. For example

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringBootApplicationTests {


    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        final ResponseEntity<Health> entity = this.restTemplate.getForEntity("/health", Health.class);
        assertThat(entity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(OK);
    }

}
```

This should work for you.

I'm adding pom.xml which shows which dependencies you need to add to your pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>no.hassan.bones</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-backbone</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-exmaple-jersey-mvc</name>
    <description>Doing Spring Boot with jersey and spring web-mvc</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>               
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

As you can see that I'm using both spring mvc i.e. `spring-boot-starter-web` and jersey as well `spring-boot-starter-jersey`. Please remember that you need to add a `@Configuration` class which register your Jerse rest endpoints. Here is a sample class for you

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * @author Iftikhar Ul Hassan
 */

@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("package.path.where.HealthController.resides");

    }
}
```

Now you can serve your jersey rest enpoints under `/rest/**`

Comment: I tried this but got `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate';`

Comment: I see now that it was not clear that I was using JAX-RS. I have updated that into my post.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@Contorller` annotation and tried `@Component`?

It would be nice to see your pom.xml

Comment: don't forget to add maven dependency

`spring-boot-starter-test`

Comment: I am at work now and I did not push the code. I can't confirm right now but think I did all the things you noted. Anyways I do think using `@Controller` or `@RestController` is the right thing to do. Also `@WebMvcTest` worked when I used Spring Controllers rather than JAX-RS (tip from Andy Wilkinson). I want to test with `@WebMvcTest` but also use JAX-RS if possible but servlet filering seems to be the issue.

Comment: I have added spring-boot-starter-test, but also -jersey, -web, -data-jpa, -actuator

Comment: I've updated my answer, tyr this, it's a working solution.

Comment: Thanks but I have all the dependencies, I have tried `@Component`, and there are no restTemplate available and have not been for some time (used to be initialized in earlier versions). I cannot define it my self. I cannot see why you would change the path. Cant see how it could work in your end. Anyways this is not what I want. I do want `@WebMvcTest` to work with JAX-RS and it seems it do not. Thanx anyways for your effort.